# Difficulty of making Space Invaders in GTK+?

Tags: gtk

What are the difficulties of making Space Invaders using GTK+ (latest stable) in C?

I did it once in high school with Visual Basic so I figured it wouldn't be that hard with GTK, but now I'm confused on even where to get started?

Can someone point me in the right directly, perhaps like how to put 1 alien on the screen and have it go back and forth?

Comment: Hi Wag2639. Why not take a few seconds to accept answers to some of your other questions. It doesn't take long and makes people far more inclined to provide an answer for you.

Comment: Some of them I only got 1 or 2 answers and I didn't feel they answer the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [short introduction](http://users.swing.be/diederen/gdk-image-pixmap.html) to game programming on X-Windows with the GTK+ toolkit.  I hope this will get you started rendering the figures on the screen.